# How do I see how many downloads from releases?

Tags: gitlab

As the title mentioned, I'd like to see how many downloads each of my releases. Being able to see total downloads across all releases is a bonus too.

I am aware of https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_statistics.html but I honestly don't really know how to use it or where. Do I just run it in the command prompt or...?

I have not tried anything yet as I'm not even sure where to start.